# Bad Python package organization installed a `tests` package to my path? (Anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools, pypi

Somehow (due to some bad advice) I believe have been [bitten](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/05/25/python-packaging/#the-structure) by [using](https://hynek.me/articles/testing-packaging/) a [shoddy](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html) organization of my project directory.

It currently looks like this (GOOD!):

```
\projectname
   setup.py
   LICENSE
   MANIFEST.in
   README.rst
   CHANGELOG.rst
   \src
      \projectname
         __init__.py
   \tests
      __init__.py
      test1.py
```

However, it used to look like this (BAD!):

```
\package_name
   setup.py
   LICENSE
   MANIFEST.in
   README.rst
   CHANGELOG.rst
   \projectname <--- main package at top level
      __init__.py
   \tests
      test1.py
```

Prior to fixing my shoddy setup, I was using an editable install of the project (`python setup.py develop`). I have subsequently removed (`pip uninstall my_package`) that install (and re-added) several times.

Despite removing it, I have now discovered that I seem to have a package called `tests` available for importing! And the package path is pointed to the directory of my project:

```
>>> import tests
>>> tests.__path__
_NamespacePath(['c:\\users\\username\\projects\\projectname\\tests'])
```

I am guessing this happened as a result of installing my package using the initial broken package organization.

**How can I remove this `tests` "package" from my path?** I am using Anaconda 4.3 (latest version). `pip uninstall tests` was not successful.

NOTE: My project has also been published to pypi (project name: parmatter) and I did install it once from there as a test, but only after using the modified project organization structure, so I don't think this was the cause. If anyone wants to install it and see if it leads to the same problem, that may at least help me nail down the cause.

Project repo:  https://github.com/Ricyteach/parmatter

Source distribution: [parmatter-0.0.5.tar.gz](https://pypi.python.org/packages/be/06/337f43391b4ac32b51cf6cc2fce4cfa40be835d1f3925a69080ef73ad4a1/parmatter-0.0.5.tar.gz#md5=ca2ec59e2deb7c10ec7dd8f3342b1f1a)

---

### EDIT

Result of `python -m site` below.

```
C:\>python -m site
sys.path = [
    'C:\\',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\python36.zip',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\DLLs',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Sphinx-1.5.6-py3.6.egg',
    'c:\\users\\ricky\\projects\\parmatter',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin',
    'C:\\Users\\ricky\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg',
]
USER_BASE: 'C:\\Users\\ricky\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: 'C:\\Users\\ricky\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python36\\site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

It appears I need to remove the project directory from `site`... how do I do that? And how did it get there in the first place?

Comment: i think you can try `pip uninstall tests`

Comment: @PaulH no, doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by OP installing an old version of the project in development mode, using the system Python interpreter instead of in a venv (*hint*: don't do that).  That creates a line in `easy-install.pth` which makes project dir(s) available in `sys.path`.

Locate the `easy-install.pth` file in your `site-packages` directory, and remove any lines starting like this:

```
c:\\users\\username\\projects
```

As for your project structure,
**I recommend you remove `__init__.py` from the tests subdirectory.**  It is not needed, and means you'll have to explicitly exclude `tests` if you're using `find_packages()` helper.

I installed your v0.0.5 distribution, and the problem does not remain in that version.  Your distribution is broken for Python 2, you should include `python_requires='>=3'` in the `setup.py` setup call so that appropriate metadata will be generated to prevent pip from attempting to install it on Python 2.

Comment: Hmmm. The module object doesn't have a `__file__` attribute. It has a `__package__` attribute, but it points directly to my project tests directory and I can't delete that (obviously).

Comment: Yes, it imports no matter what directory I am in. BTW: I have looked for `.egg-link` files in the `site-packages` directory, but there aren't any.

Comment: yes, having `__init__.py` in `tests` was a mistake. I no longer have one in there, but the problem still remains.

Comment: Does it only import from within your venv, or does it import in your system python too?  Please cd to /tmp and edit to include the output of `python -m site` in your question.

Comment: I did not create a venv.(another noob mistake) so it imports from the main system install. I created a new env using `conda create` and it will not import from that env. Updating `python -m site` now.

Comment: Hmmm It looks like the project directory is in the path somehow. Can I just edit the PATH variable and remove that....? I am looking at my environment table and do not see the project directory anywhere...

Comment: OK, I see what your big mistake was now.  You did an editable install, outside of a virtualenv.  That's why `c:\\users\\ricky\\projects\\parmatter` is in `sys.path`.

Comment: Excellent. Yes, it appears in `sys.path`. It is in the middle of the list. However it is pointing to the project tests directory. I'm using that directory to store my tests and can't delete it... any idea how I can cause that directory to disappear from `sys.path`? Should I try restarting the computer?

Comment: New theory: it is persisting because I have been running a `jupyter` console for several days and it is holding a reference to `sys.path`? Checking. EDIT: nope. still there after closing jupyter. going to just restart and see if that helps.

Comment: No, this stuff is done by `.pth` files, which `site.py` uses, and probably won't fixed by a restart.  See [here](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=development%20mode#develop-deploy-the-project-source-in-development-mode).  Find the `easy-install.pth` file on your disk and remove the line about that.

Comment: Confirmed and FIXED. Great work. Thank you for the info about `python_requires='>=3'`; I had missed that one in the docs. Project has been updated.